Strange printf not working after a getchar and getchar skipping
I'm getting crazy with C.
I'm programming with JavaScript, Ruby, Python, PHP, Lua, even Java...
Recently, I tried to program a simple Read-Eval-Print-Loop in C.
And I have a very strange behavior with this simple, basic, code, on Windows 10.
This code is compiled with the standard toolchain of Visual Studio.

sometimes (it is impossible to predict), the reading of the string is skipped. I guessed there must be some garbage in the stdin but I can't flush it with fflush, right?
everytimes, all the printf AFTER the loop on getchar are not working. Nothing is displayed. I put \n and fflush to no avail.

Help me, you are my only hope.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    const size_t line_length = 1024;
    char * line = malloc(line_length * sizeof(char));
    memset(&line, '\0', line_length);
    char c;
    unsigned short count = 0;
    // fflush(stdin); // tried this, same thing
    printf("Enter: ");
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && count < line_length - 1) {
        line[count] = c;
        count += 1;
    }
    printf("Count : %d\n", count);
    printf("%s\n", line);
    printf("End of program.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    free(line);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Expected output:
Enter: hello
Count : 5
hello

Actual output (1):
Enter: hello 

Actual output (2):


Just use calloc() instead of malloc() + filling the memory with 0's...

You don't even need to call memset you could as well put line[count] = '\0'; right after the while loop.

Help me, you are my only hope.

There are several issues with your code:

you forgot #include <string.h> for memset
fflush(stdin) has undefined behaviour (OK, you've commented it out, but it's still good to know)
getchar() returns an int, not a char. Read this for more explanations.
and most importantly: memset(&line, '\0', line_length) is wrong it should be memset(line, '\0', line_length); (without the &), line is already the pointer to the memory you want to set to 0.

Corrected code, see my comments starting with ///
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>                      /// added

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const size_t line_length = 1024;
  char* line = malloc(line_length);
  memset(line, '\0', line_length);      /// removed & 
  int c;                                /// int instead of char
  unsigned short count = 0;
  // fflush(stdin);                     /// fflush(stdin); is UB
  printf(">>> ");
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && count < line_length - 1) {
    line[count] = c;
    count += 1;
  }
  printf("Count : %d\n", count);
  printf("%s\n", line);
  printf("End of program.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  free(line);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


@Xitog: It is important to use int c; instead of char c; because a char is not guaranteed to be able to represent the value EOF, whereas an int is. Also, even if a char is able to represent the value EOF (which is the case on most platforms), you must use an int instead of a char, because otherwise you may not be able to distinguish the value EOF from the value of an actual character. However, once you have determined that c does not have the value EOF, then you can convert the int value to a char. An explicit cast is not necessary.

Minor: line_length and count deserve to be the same type.  Recommend both size_t.

@AndreasWenzel "once you have determined that c does not have the value EOF, then you can convert the int value to a char" --> except that pedantically assigning an int value like UCHAR_MAX to a signed char invokes implementation defined behavior.  Very commonly, that is OK.  A cast does quiet some compiler warnings about narrowing in line[count] = c;, thus a cast is OK practice here.
